# factory_girl / factory_bot deeply nested associations without after(:create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

**Models:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts

  validates_presence_of :user_id
  # a blog record cannot be created without at least one associated post record
  validates :posts, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :blog_id
end
```

The validations is what makes it difficult for my factories.  Notice that a `blog` cannot be created unless it has at least one `post`.  Also notice that a `post` cannot be created unless it has a `blog_id`.  In other words: the `blog` and `post` need to be *built*, they need to be *associated* to each other, and they need to be saved at the same time so that the validations pass.

This is with Rails 5, so I did make adjustments to the `application.rb` so that `belongs_to` associations do not cause as much headache in my factories:

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
  end
end
```

**Factories:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blog do
    user 

    factory :blog_with_post do
      after(:create) do |blog, eval|
        the_user_of_blog = blog.user
        create(:post, blog: blog, user: the_user_of_blog)
      end
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    blog 
    user 
  end
end
```

What I do in my tests is create a single `user` record, and then create a `blog` record and a `post` record, both of which are associated to that same `user`.

With the above code: this works:

```
@user = create(:user)
        create(:blog_with_post, user: @user)
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User can't be blank, Posts is too short (minimum is 1 character)
```

**Attempts**

I tried `after(:build)` :

```
factory :blog_with_post do
    after(:build) do |blog, eval|
        blog_user = blog.user
        create(:post, blog: blog, user: blog_user)
    end
end

# @user = create(:user)
#         create(:blog_with_post, user: @user)
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Blog can't be blank
```

I also tried `before(:create)` which resulted in the same error:

```
factory :blog_with_post do
  before(:create) do |blog, eval|
    blog_user = blog.user
    create(:post, blog: blog, user: blog_user)
  end
end

# @user = create(:user)
#         create(:blog_with_post, user: @user)
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Blog can't be blank
```

I also attempted this:

```
factory :blog_with_post do
  after(:build) do |blog, eval|
    blog_user = blog.user
    build(:post, blog: blog, user: blog_user)
  end
end

# @user = create(:user)
#         create(:blog_with_post, user: @user)
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Posts is too short (minimum is 1 character)
```

The following seems very close, but I do not know how to reference the user associated to this blog:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blog do
    user 

    factory :blog_with_post do
      posts {build_list :post, 1, user: THE_USER_OF_THIS_BLOG}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @SebastianPalma I am not quite understanding your question.  Would you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as close as I got, and it excludes the validation that a `blog` cannot be created without at least one `post`.  I couldn't figure that out (with factories, with straight rails I could do it). However, I did figure out how to get `before(:create)` to work as opposed to using `after(:create)`.

Ultimately: it boiled down to a misunderstanding of how associations know about each other before they are saved, and how associations naturally save at the same time.

The [detailed association reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference) rails documentation helped me out a lot, combined with building records with associations, saving one of of those records, and then observing how they all save at the same time due to the `belongs_to` or the `has_many` associations specified on the model.

With that knowledge: these two validations on the `Post` model is what was causing most of the issues:

```
validates_presence_of :user_id, :blog_id
```

The issue with this (in regards to the code in this question) is that the `blog_id` will not exist when the associations are *built* but not yet *saved*, so in some situations it will be invalid with the factories.

So we don't *really* want to confirm that the ***foreign key*** is present (ex: `blog_id`).  Instead, we want to validate that the ***association*** exists.  In other words: it was simply a misuse of the [presence validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) for associations. So change the validation to this:

```
validates_presence_of :user, :blog
```

Now all that is left to do is write the factory the right way:

```
factory :blog_with_post do
  before(:create) do |blog, eval|
    create(:post, blog: blog, user: blog.user)
  end
end
```

**Usage**

```
@user = create(:user)
        create(:blog_with_post, user: @user)
```

And with that: the `blog` and the `user` are both associated to the `post`, the `user` is associated to the `post`, and all are saved at the same time.